# How to clear p:pickList target list on close of p:dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:pickList` within a `p:dialog`.

```
<p:dialog id="registerDialog" widgetVar="registerServiceDlg" modal="true" 
    minimizable="false" draggable="false" position="300,40" 
    style="background:#E0E0E0;" closable="true"  maximizable="false" 
    resizable="false"  visible="#{not empty facesContext.maximumSeverity}">

    <p:ajax event="close" update="registerDialog" />
    <h:outputLabel value="User" styleClass="label"/>
    <p:pickList id="contactBean" value="#{contactBean.contacts}" var="contact" 
        itemLabel="#{contact}" itemValue="#{contact}" style="margin-left:20px;" 
        required="true" requiredMessage="one user is needed"/>
</p:dialog>
```

On close of the dialog, I want to clear `p:pickList` target list. How can I achieve this? The bean is in session scope and I want to retain it in session scope itself.

Comment: You either want to bind picklist's value attribute to something else, so that it could be cleared without disturbing the session, or clear the list that is found in the session scoped bean, so that the values would be updated. Also, you need a listener in your `<p:ajax>` tag to make it do its work upon close.

Comment: It would also be great if you added the functional requirements and your general setup in your question (what is in session, what is in the picklist, etc.).

Comment: What exactly is your concrete problem? At which step exactly are you stucking while implementing the requirement accordingly? Are you aware of possibility to invoke a bean method via `<p:ajax listener>`?

Answer (score 1):

Bind your target list again on your `@PostConstruct` method;

```
contacts.setTarget(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Your answer is vague. Either make it a comment, or expand your explanation.

Comment: What is vague in my answer? It's clear I think. In postconstruct method, need to bind targetList by using targetlist setter method of picklist.

Comment: The OP clearly states that "**on closing of a dialog** i want to clear picklist". What does it have to do with bean instantiation? Also remember, that "bean is in **session scope**", and it has already been instantiated. What has to be done is attaching a close listener to the dialog, like `<p:ajax event="close" listener="#{bean.dialogClosed}">` with the appropriate method that clears the data OP wants, by having a call to the method you proposed.